# URL is not loading in webview android

Tags: android, webview, cleartext

I am developing an android app for my website and in the webview i need to load (https://dl.flipkart.com/dl/flipstart-days-store?affid=admingopai&affExtParam2=75&affExtParam1=10317EE844E611E&1580556780117=1) url. but it doesn't load it is showing a blank page. It is getting loaded in web browser and android brower too and all the other urls from the website are getting loaded too except for this one.. it gives me a CLEAR TEXT error but i have tried using network_config in xlm and adding clear text enable into the manifest file too
please help

**EDIT**

```
webview.loadUrl(url,preventCaching);
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(getResources().getString(R.string.
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
    WebSettings set = mainBinding.webview.getSettings();
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    set.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and my webclient looks like this

```
class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainBinding.splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        },2000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, please, show your code

Comment: @MaxShwed i've updated my question and added my webview code

Comment: Hm, maybe try to replace `loadUrl` above the `webSettings` properties ?

Comment: @MaxShwed I'm sorry i don't understand. Can you tell me a bit in detail

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong :)